# How can I enable autocomplete text support in Notepad++

Tags: autocomplete, notepad++

There's already a question on this here. But i want to know if its possible to add autocomplete text support in a .txt file for english words (maybe from GNU Aspell dictionary)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something I've pondered myself, you could copy loads of "words" into the keyword list within the user-defined language dialogue.  Not the best way!

If you have a look at the XML file in (vista);

C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\userDefineLang.xml

Then you can see keywords are kept in one line.  I bet, if you made have the entire english dictionary then it would likely crash notepad++.

You could put your idea into the Notepad++ IdeaTorrent for the developers too consider;

http://sourceforge.net/apps/ideatorrent/notepad-plus/ideatorrent/

UPDATE 06/11/2011 :

May I also add that a plugin now available for highlight misspelt words and auto correction.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/squiggly/